# How can i prevent creating batch tables using spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch application where I am reading data from External Source.But when the jobs run, it tries to Create and Insert data in Batch_Job_instance table in source DB but the user does not have any permission .  How do i prevent the creation of these tables in Source DB ?

Can anyone help ?

Below is the error log

> 16:46:00,491 ERROR
>   [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler]
>   (pool-9-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT into
>   BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values
>   (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

```
17:55:00,467 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-9-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.elm.salamah.scheduler.batch.configuration.EmployeeBatchConfiguration.performThirdJob(EmployeeBatchConfiguration.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:877)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
        ... 47 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

Comment: Hi, I am not able to achieve it using the solution in the post you mentioned.I tried this property spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false but it sill tries to access Source DB. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is trying to do the initialization?  Are you using Spring Boot?  A full stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Edited the Question and added the stack trace. Can you please check ? ..and Yes i am using Spring boot with Spring batch. My Source is : Oracle DB , Destination is : Sql Server

Comment: It is better to post your data-source-context. For now, check your datasource configuration whether you have source DB configuration in it and also verify the "jdbc:initialize-database" configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the table creation extending your Configuration class from DefaultBatchConfigurer and overriding the setDataSource() method and setting null. This approach will enable in-memory Map Repository.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    [...]
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(null);
    }
}
```