# How can we disable the creation of meta data tables while keeping the database connection in spring boot batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've data-source properties in my application.properties, but i don't want spring batch to create meta tables in my database.
Do we have a way to keep the data-source but stop spring batch from creating the meta data files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following property in your application.properties file:

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never
```

This will prevent creating meta data tables in your data source. You can find more details on this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database

Comment: Sadly, that's now flagged as "deprecated" and, at least for me, no longer works.  =(

Comment: The new property is `spring.batch.initialize-schema=never`. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Adding this property doesn't work for me. I still get the same error "Invalid object name BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE"

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off the database initialization explicitly by setting `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema` to `never`, as follows:

```
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
```

```yaml
spring:
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
```