# I want to use a read only account to run select query on maria db and export the result via spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am required to use a read only account to run select query on maria db and export the result via spring batch.
at the moment i am getting "update denied for user".
i want the batch to not update the database.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.MyProject</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringBatchDatabaseToCsv</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>SpringBatchDatabaseToCsv</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
 <parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
 <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.0.4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
 <plugins>
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

User.java

```
public class User {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 public Integer getId() {
 return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
 this.id = id;
 }
 public String getName() {
 return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
 }
}
```

UserItemProcessor.java

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import com.MyProject.model.User;
public class UserItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, User> {
 @Override
 public User process(User user) throws Exception {
 return user;
 }
}
```

BatchConfiguration.java

> package com.MyProject;
> import java.sql.ResultSet;
> import java.sql.SQLException;
> import javax.sql.DataSource;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
> import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
> import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
> import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
> import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor;
> import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
> import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
> import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
> import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
>
> ```
> import com.MyProject.model.User;
> @Configuration
> @EnableBatchProcessing
> public class BatchConfiguration {
>  @Autowired
>  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
>  @Autowired
>  public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
>  @Autowired
>  public DataSource dataSource;
>  @Bean
>  public DataSource dataSource() {
>  final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
>  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/springbatch");
>  dataSource.setUsername("root");
>  dataSource.setPassword("root");
>  return dataSource;
>  }
>  
>  @Bean
>  public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader(){
>  JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<User>();
>  reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
>  reader.setSql("SELECT id,name FROM user");
>  reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
>  return reader;
>  }
>  
>  public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User>{
>  @Override
>  public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
>  User user = new User();
>  user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
>  user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
>  return user;
>  }
>  }
>  
>  @Bean
>  public UserItemProcessor processor(){
>  return new UserItemProcessor();
>  }
>  
>  @Bean
>  public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
>  FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
>  writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
>  writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {{
>  setDelimiter(",");
>  setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {{
>  setNames(new String[] { "id", "name" });
>  }});
>  }});
>   return writer;
>  }
>  
>  @Bean
>  public Step step1() {
>  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User, User> chunk(10)
>  .reader(reader())
>  .processor(processor())
>  .writer(writer())
>  .build();
>  }
>  
>  @Bean
>  public Job exportUserJob() {
>  return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
>  .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
>  .flow(step1())
>  .end()
>  .build();
>  }
>  }
> ```

Comment: i created batch as per https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/03/spring-boot-batch-read-from-mysql-database-and-write-into-a-csv-file-tutorial.html (did not use the create data base part). when i ran the program it gave an error - UPDATE command denied to user 'arihant'@'10.16.49.23' for table 'TASK_SEQ', i am not updating anything in database still getting this erro

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code that perform the mentioned query. Did you use the exact same sql query as the tutorial?

Comment: added in question description

Comment: error - UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'10.123.23.88' for table 'TASK_SEQ'

Comment: basically i want to prevent creating batch tables - as the account being used is readonly

Comment: @arihanqt See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48500494/5019386.