# Spring batch meta-data tables in DynamoDB

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb, spring-batch

I have a spring-boot batch application.
Where I'm pulling data from redshift to dump in elastic search.
And I also have a dynamoDB available for the application.

Now, my question is:

**is it possible to store the spring-batch meta-data tables in DynamoDB or to avoid the meta-data tables at-all?**

Some of the things, I have tried so far,

tried to avoid the meta-data tables creation, by using `ResourcelessTransactionManager`

```
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }
```

**OR**

By overriding `setDataSource` to do nothing

```
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // do nothing
    }
```

But both the case, it's not reading data from `Redshift`.

Secondly, I didn't find any reference to use dynamoDB to store spring-batch meta-data tables.

**Therefore, is there any approach to store meta schema in dynamoDb or the avoid these tables without affecting Redshift data reading from ItemReader?**

My ItemReader Code:

```
    public ItemReader<MyPojo> redshiftReader(@Qualifier("redShiftDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<MyPojo> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_TO_READ_DATA);
        databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyPojo>(MyPojo.class));
        databaseReader.setFetchSize(10000);

        return databaseReader;
    }
```

```
SPRING BOOT VERSION: 2.2.2.RELEASE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

Comment: Spring Batch does not support DynamoDB as a job repository OOTB. To use the in-memory map based job repository, please refer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine can we still not integrate Spring batch with dynamoDB ?

Comment: No, DynamoDB is not supported by Spring Batch.