# SpringBoot batch with JPARepository without persisting meta data into DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I want to create a spring-batch job, which will save data into SQL Server tables, but I want to run it without any meta data database persistence. Unfortunately spring-batch requires to write metadata information of job execution.

I don't want those BATCH table to be created. How can I do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

Answer (score 1):

Those tables are required for proper functioning of the spring-batch framework features, so I don't think its a good idea. However Spring does provide a in-memory solution.

The `JobRepository` has a few `Dao` classes. Eg. `JobInstanceDao`, `JobExecutionDao` etc. All of these by default use the `JDBC` implementation. But Spring also provides a in-memory implementation for these eg. `MapJobInstanceDao` for `JobInstanceDao`. You can easily inject these through the constructor of `SimpleJobRepository`.

Comment: I have tried MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean but in that case I am using ResourcelessTransactionManager which is causing issue. I am not being able to save data after that.

Comment: Seems like you are using the same transaction manager globally ? Make sure the `ResourcelessTransactionManager` is not picked up by the business logic classes.

Comment: How to have separate transaction manager for JPA repository. I tried using @Transactional at service layer but it did not help.

Comment: I am sure you already have some transaction manager setup. Keep it as is. Define a bean of `ResourcelessTransactionManager` and pass it into the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` only. Unless I am missing something this should work.

Comment: `ResourcelessTransactionManager` is basically a no-op transaction manager. Using this essentially means dropping support of transactions.

Comment: I don't have any transaction manager setup for JPA as it is already handled by JPA, but it is not working in case I am using Resourcelesstransactionmanager for MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean. Can you suggest some examples.

Comment: Do it like following, inject `ResourcelessTransactionManager` into MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean"> <property name="transactionManager">
 <bean class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
</property>
</bean>

Comment: Tried this but still facing same issue. Batch is running with Map based repository but not saving data into db.